# How to implement background sync with nuxtjs/pwa?

Tags: vuejs2, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js

I am trying to use workbox background-sync in Nuxtjs via `@nuxt/pwa-module`.

this is my workbox property in `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
workbox: {

    importScripts : [
        'sw-background-sync.js'
    ]

}
```

contents of `plugins/sw-background-sync.js` file :

```
console.log("backsync called")
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    'https:\/\/example.com\/api\/Survey\/post.*',
    new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly({
        plugins: [
            new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('myQueueName', {
                maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60
            })
        ]
    }),
    'POST'
);
```

Offline caching is supposed to work by default and it is working fine. but when I uncomment  importScripts and refresh the page I get this error in console :

```
backsync called
workbox-sw.js:1 Uncaught Error: Config must be set before accessing workbox.* modules
    at Proxy.setConfig (workbox-sw.js:1)
    at sw.js:8
```

Any example of how to implement pwa background sync with nuxtjs would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I should put the script inside  `workboxExtensions` property in nuxt.config.js file:

```
workbox: {

    workboxExtensions : '@/plugins/sw-background-sync.js'
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `workboxExtensions` and `plugins`?

Comment: sw-background-sync is actually a plugin that you should use it in `workboxExtensions` option to work. it is just how pwa module works. it's a convention

Answer (score 0):

When using workbox you can also put:

```
 strategyPlugins:[{
        use:'BackgroundSync',
        config: {}
      }],
```

I am still trying to find out what config to put in there.